# Enabling Compiz "Extra" or "Normal" effects per bash in Ubuntu

Tags: compiz, bash, scripts

Enabling disabling compiz per bash is pretty simple per `compiz --replace`,

But how can I switch between the None / Normal / Extra -- Visual Effects in the "`gnome-appearance-properties`" **only using a shell**..

*PS. This is for a kiosk mode pc, which will have NO mouse/keyboard devices attached! gnome panel menus and everything is disabled...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I peeked at the sources for gnome-control-center (`apt-get source gnome-control-center`,  then in `debian/patches/95_desktop-effects-integration.patch` it adds the options for the compiz settings.). For setting Normal effects it appears to unset `/apps/compiz/general/allscreens/options/active_plugins` (in gconf) so that it gets set back to default. For Extra effects it appears to do the same, but appends `shift` and `wobbly` to the list.

To browse and edit gconf visually, use `gconf-editor`.
To query and edit gconf settings from a shell, you need to use `gconftool`

So if the above information pans out, `man gconftool` should set you on the right track.

Comment: I was assuming it was something like that.. That is more or less better than what I wanted in the first place..